# Sed replace on CRLF not working

Tags: shell-script, centos, sed

Input:

```
bharti+bharti-ims+bharti-sdm+RuleForBhartiOnlyIndices+kibana_user
```

Desired Output:

```
"bharti","bharti-ims","bharti-sdm","RuleForBhartiOnlyIndices","kibana_user"
```

Command:

```
echo "bharti+bharti-ims+bharti-sdm+RuleForBhartiOnlyIndices+kibana_user" | sed -e 's/^/"/g' -e 's/+/","/g' -e 's/$/\"/g'
```

This is working fine and am getting the desired output where the line terminator is LF. 
As soon as i edit the file in windows and save it the line terminator LF is replaced by CRLF.
And the last sed expression where i replace end of line `$` with `"` is failing and getting unexpected result. 
Unexpected Result:

```
"bharti","bharti-ims","bharti-sdm","RuleForBhartiOnlyIndices","kibana_user
```

Look at the missing `"` at the the end.

Any sed experts out there who can come for my rescue please :).

Comment: see also: [Why does
my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quote is actually there, but it has replaced the initial quote when printing to screen:

```
$ printf '%s\r\n' 'foo' | sed -e 's/^/"/g' -e 's/+/","/g' -e 's/$/\"/g' | od --format c
0000000   "   f   o   o  \r   "  \n
0000007
```

`\r`/CR/carriage return, moves the position of the virtual cursor used to output text to the start of the line, so the final `"` ends up overwriting (in the terminal only) the first quote.

You may want to send the input through `dos2unix` first, unless you're willing to add `sed` expressions to handle `\r`.

Comment: Thank you, i couldn't think of the dos2unix utility.

Answer (score 1):

You can refine the `sed` expression to eliminate the `\r` in case it's there:

```
sed -e 's/^/"/' -e 's/+/","/g' -e 's/\r*$/"/' file
```

As begin-of-line and end-of line exist just once in a line, the `g` flag can be dropped. No need to escape the double quotes in the "replacement". Use "alternation" to further simplify:

```
sed -e 's/^\|\r*$/"/g' -e 's/+/","/g' file
```

Comment: Thank you Rudic.